# Call API Platform default operation from a custom one?

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm working on security zone. After spending days on Symfony and API Platform docs, i realised that my concern is particula. 
Talking about security in Symfony, I think it's cool for small or internal projects. We can add/remove profiles/roles like we want.

I want to do something special. I want user or client (who is not dev) to be able via the back office, add new profiles and assign rights. I use security zone instead of roles directly. I want to protect my actions(controller) under security zone.

Each controller gets "getSecurityZone()" method which can allow me to check that first (onkernel event) to see if the current user has rights (depending on their -unique- role/profile) on the ressource.

```
public function securityZone(): string
{
    return 'BO_ZONE';
}
```

My concern: I don't want to rewrite the logic to retrieve data since API Platform already does it. So i tried to use event to run my security check. It seems working but How to call default operation (like GET) from my action ?

My entity :

```
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "path"="/users",
 *              "controller"=UserListAction::class,
 *              "defaults"={"_api_receive"=false},
 *              "swagger_context"={
 *                  "parameters"={
 *
 *                  }
 *              },
 *          },
 *          "post"
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
```

My eventlistener :

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::VIEW => ['encodePassword', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE],
        KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => ['micheckSecurity', EventPriorities::PRE_READ],
    ];
}

//..

public function micheckSecurity(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller =  $event->getController();
    $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

    if (Request::METHOD_GET !== $method || $controller->getSecurityZone() !== Constants::SECZONE_BO_ZONE)
        throw new AccessDeniedException("You are not author", 500);
    return;
}
```

And my action(controller) :

```
class UserListAction
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        //Call default operation which return collection
    }

    public function securityZone(): string
    {
        return 'BO_ZONE';
    }

}
```

In my _invoke() method, I want to call the read method of API Platform which will return the collection automatically.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are default API Platform operations are stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254473/where-are-default-api-platform-operations-are-stored)