# Where are default API Platform operations are stored?

Tags: php, api, symfony, platform, api-platform.com

I would like to know where are default API Platform operations (CRUD methods) are stored so that I can call them wherever I need.

I need it because when I define my custom operations, I want to call them (default operations) so that I don't need to rewrite the code (like, get a collection of resource).

For example:

```
class GetResourceListAction
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        //Do my things here

        //And finally call default operation which return collection
    }    
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers) you can directly return your Collection and the API Platform operation will do the rest.

Ex :

```php
    public function __invoke(Book $data): Book
    {
        $this->bookPublishingHandler->handle($data);

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. What was I thinking of :')